# Limit of $f(x,y)$ as $(x,y)$ goes to $0$.

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Show that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y) = \frac{3x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$.
If the limit is approached along the line $y = cx$, for $c\in \mathbb{R}$, then
\begin{equation*}
f(x,y) = f(x,cx) = \frac{3x^2cx}{x^2+c^2x^2} = \frac{3cx^3}{x^2+c^2x^2} = \frac{3cx^3}{x^2(1+c^2)} = \frac{3cx}{1+c^2}.
\end{equation*}
Hence, $\lim_{\substack{(x,y)\to (0,0) \\ \text{along} \, \, y = cx}} \frac{3cx}{1+c^2} = 0$.

If the limit is approached along the line $y = cx^2$, for $c\in \mathbb{R}$, then
\begin{equation*}
f(x,y) = f(x,cx^2) = \frac{3x^2cx^2}{x^2+c^2x^4} = \frac{3cx^4}{x^2+c^2x^4} = \frac{3cx^4}{x^2(1+c^2x^2)} = \frac{3cx^2}{1+c^2x^2}.
\end{equation*}
Hence, $\lim_{\substack{(x,y)\to (0,0) \\ \text{along} \, \, y = cx^2}} \frac{3cx^2}{1+c^2x^2} = 0$.

If the limit is approached along the line $y = 0$, then $\lim_{\substack{(x,y)\to (0,0) \\ \text{along} \, \, y=0}} \frac{0}{x^2+0} = 0$.

So now we suspect that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y) = 0$. But how would we do this officially? Is it the $\epsilon-\delta$ way? If so how would we do this? Thanks.

Comment: $|f(x,y)|\leq\frac{3|x|}{2}$ since $|x||y|\leq\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}$.

Comment: You can use polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(x,y) \not = (0,0).$

$|\dfrac{3x^2y}{x^2+y^2}|= \dfrac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}|3y|\le 1\cdot 3|y|\le 3(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$.

Choose $\delta =\epsilon/3.$

Note: $|y| =\sqrt{y^2} \le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: Let's show this formally using an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof. For $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$, let $\epsilon > 0$. Then if $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $|(x,y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$, then
\begin{equation*}
|y|^2\leq x^2+y^2 < \frac{\epsilon^2}{9},
\end{equation*}
so $|y| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$. Thus,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\left|\frac{3x^2y}{x^2+y^2}-0\right| &= \left|\frac{3x^2y}{x^2+y^2}\right| \\
&= \frac{3x^2|y|}{x^2+y^2} \\
&\leq \frac{3x^2y}{x^2} \\
&= 3|y| \\
&< \epsilon
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
and we are done.

Comment: Is fine your proof.